# why my if statement alternates with else every time i run the function

Tags: javascript, ajax, if-statement, height, width

So here i made a function from a button to upload images using ajax to show on the canvas but to specify the width and height I use the if statement. I specify if width greater than height the `width = 300` and `height = 200`, if width less than height `width = 200` and `height = 300`.

But i dont know how the if i click the button for first time after refresh my page the if statement is not correct or else sometime it is. And the next following click is alternately. Here my code.

```
      var image2 = new Image();   
      image2.src = '../img/template/'+e; 
      tmpWidht = parseInt(image2.width);
      tmpHeight = parseInt(image2.height);

      if( tmpWidht > tmpHeight ){
        var imgWidth = 300;
        var imgHeight = 200;
      }else{
        var imgWidth = 200;
        var imgHeight = 300;
      }
```

Comment: Is the image “e” the same both times?  You may be setting the src, but the image doesn’t load immediately. You may need to attach the rest to an event on the image like image2.onload = function() { if ...}

Answer (score 0):

ah sorry this is the all of my success ajax code

```
var id = e+varImg;
      var image2 = new Image();   
      image2.src = '../img/template/'+e; 
      tmpWidht = parseInt(image2.width);
      tmpHeight = parseInt(image2.height);

      if( tmpWidht > tmpHeight ){
        var imgWidth = 300;
        var imgHeight = 200;
      }else{
        var imgWidth = 200;
        var imgHeight = 300;
      }

      image2.onload = function(){
        var img2 = new Konva.Image({
        x:50,
        y:50,
        width: imgWidth,
        height: imgHeight,
        image: image2,
        id: id,
        draggable: true
        });

      layer.add(img2);
      layer.draw();
```